# Pandas cumulative count by looking at if two lists have common value

Tags: string, pandas, match, cumulative-sum

If I have a table like this

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      time           | list of string   |
|---------------------|------------------|
| 2019-06-18 09:05:00 |   ['A', 'B', 'C']|
|---------------------|------------------|
| 2019-06-19 09:05:00 |   ['A', 'C']     |
|---------------------|------------------|
| 2019-06-19 09:05:00 |   ['B', 'C']     |
|---------------------|------------------|
| 2019-06-20 09:05:00 |   ['C']          |
|---------------------|------------------|
| 2019-06-20 09:05:00 |   ['A', 'B', 'C']|
|---------------------|------------------|
```

For each row, I would like to know how many rows prior to the current timestamp have at least one common value to the current list of string.

The slow code would be something like this:

```
results = [] for i in range(len(df)):
    current_t = df['time'].iloc[i]
    current_string = df['list_of_string'].iloc[i]
    df_before_t = df[df['time']<current_t]
    cumm_count = 0
    for row in df_before_t['list_of_string']:
        if (set(current_string) & set(row)):
            cumm_count += 1
    results.append(cumm_count)
```

So the result table would be:

```
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|      time           | list of string   |   result            |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
| 2019-06-18 09:05:00 |   ['A', 'B', 'C']|           0         |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
| 2019-06-19 09:05:00 |   ['A', 'C']     |           1         |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
| 2019-06-19 09:05:00 |   ['D']          |           0         |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
| 2019-06-20 09:05:00 |   ['C']          |           2         |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
| 2019-06-20 09:05:00 |   ['A', 'B', 'C']|           2         |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
```

The dataset I currently have is relatively large and I would like to get help to process this data fast. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is converting lists to sets and using listcomp on `list of string` and compare against `time` to those less than current `time`

```
s = df['list of string'].map(set)
t = pd.to_datetime(df.time)

df['result'] = [sum(len(x & y) != 0 for y in s[t.iloc[i] > t]) 
                                        for i,x in enumerate(s)]

Out[283]:
                  time list of string  result
0  2019-06-18 09:05:00      [A, B, C]       0
1  2019-06-19 09:05:00         [A, C]       1
2  2019-06-19 09:05:00            [D]       0
3  2019-06-20 09:05:00            [C]       2
4  2019-06-20 09:05:00      [A, B, C]       2
```

Comment: Thanks very much. But if the same timestamp exists in multiple rows, I need to get the count for the rows that happened before the current row being compared. How would I modify the code?

Comment: But in that case, row with `[D]` should be 1 because its `time` is  the same as row `[A, C]` ?

Comment: For the row with [D], only the first row is eligible to compare (2019-06-18 09:05:00 is before 2019-06-19 09:05:00). So because [A, B, C] and [D] don't have a common value, the result for row with [D] is 0.

Comment: @M.Cong: hah! I undestand now. Just a minor change. I edited the answer. Check my updated